# Populate array with pre constructed classes OnInit aka using type as value

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created a class, made all interface values optional, assigned placeholder values in the constructor, exported it, imported it, declared it at the top of my component and now trying to use `this.cards = [ new Card(), new Card() ]` and it is not working.

I have tried: 
`public cards: Card[] = []` ,
`this.cards = [ new Card({ descriptorLeft: '', descriptorRight: '' ... })`

I am expecting to be able to call `new Card()` and the constructor would build the objects for me, however, it gives me the error message `'Card' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`

Code below:

```
interface HeaderInfo {
    header: String;
    text: String;
}

interface ICard {
    descriptorLeft?: String;
    descriptorRight?: String;
    growth?: {
        arrow: Number;
        percent: Number;
    };
    dateOne?: HeaderInfo;
    error?: String;
}

/*
    Top cards on the dashboard page.
*/
export class Card {
    public descriptorLeft: String;
    public descriptorRight: String;
    public growth: {
        arrow: Number;
        percent: Number;
    };
    public dateOne: {
        header: String;
        text: String;
    };
    public dateTwo: {
        header: String;
        text: String;
    };
    public isLoading: Boolean;
    public error: String;

    constructor(obj?: IKpiCard) {
        this.descriptorLeft = obj.descriptorLeft || 'Descriptor left.';
        this.descriptorRight = obj.descriptorRight || 'Descriptor right.';
        this.growth = {
            arrow: 0 || this.iconDirectionHandler(obj.growth.percent),
            percent: 1 || obj.growth.percent
        };
        this.dateOne = {
            header: 'Date One.' || obj.dateOne.header,
            text: 'Text for Date One.' || obj.dateOne.text
        };
        this.error = null || obj.error;
    }

    private iconDirectionHandler(val): Number {
      ...
    }
}
```

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Card } from 'src/app/scripts/interfaces/card';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-dashboard',
    templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss']
})

export class PageDashboardComponent implements OnInit {
    public cards: Card[];

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.cards = [
            new Card(),
            new Card(),
            new Card()
        ];
        console.log('Cards:', this.cards);
    }
}
```

Comment: most likely you are not importing the right `Card` object. You seem to be importing an interface from `interfaces/card`. Are you sure the class Card is not in another file?

Comment: Sorry @PierreDuc, I didn't see your comment, post your answer

Comment: Thanks for answering. The import path is how it is supposed to be. Yes, you are correct that I should refactor and have a separate folder for classes, or, blueprints. However, I am importing the correct class.

Comment: @Prozak can you try to make a reproduction on stackblitz, because the only way this cannot work is when the import is wrong

Comment: @Daniel no problem :) it even seems like it wasn't the right answer for some reason

Comment: Please note that your card class is expecting an object parameter in the constructor constructor(obj?: IKpiCard). It is optional, but a few lines below you do obj.descriptorLeft which won't work if obj is undefined.
and when calling new Card() you do not pass an obj.
Apart from that I think your code is incomplete as I was able to reproduce and had no such error as you describe.
So please do as @PierreDuc suggested and provide code to reproduce the error.